# Dual booting doesn't load Windows anymore

Tags: grub2, windows-7

The grub2 used to work just fine with a purple screen pause and used to load Windows and Ubuntu as required. I used to run both OS on the same machine and both used to work just fine, but now when I try to launch Windows, it takes forever at the purple screen pause and it doesn't proceed further.

What caused this problem? What is the solution?

I used to run *Windows 7 Ultimate* and *14.01 Ubuntu* side by side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove windows, or did you recently install updates?  If so, you might just need to update the bootloader.  Run this at the command line (assuming your GRUB install is in /boot/grub/):

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

If your grub install is somewhere else, try reinstalling GRUB:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

(assuming your computer boots to /dev/sda first)

That should solve the issue.  If not, then your Windows install may be corrupt.  If this doesn't fix it, use your computer's BIOS menu to boot manually on the Windows partition.  If it doesn't boot, then your Windows install died.

Comment: well I did install updates I'll try if this fixes my problem and share a thumbs up if its solved

Comment: the first command asks me to run the command in root. I really dont know how to do that and the second command doesnt grant me the permission to reinstall

Comment: Ugh, sorry, see correction above...

Comment: add sudo  to the beginning

Comment: gives me the following text
"Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
  No volume groups found
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
done
"

Comment: Perfect.  Try booting now

Comment: It should work.